# Using italics of newtx math in newpx package

Tags: newtxmath, newtx

Suppose I want to use the italics of [`newtxmath`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/newpx) package in `newpxmath` in the math mode what should I do?

Is it possible to change certain letters of `newpxmath` to `newtxmath` in the math mode? For example, I want the letter `f` of the `newtxmath` in the `newpxmath` package. Is it possible?

Comment: @svend Thanks for doing the edit. Its now more clear.

Comment: Yes, it is possible, with long work. And I mean long.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks. Like how? Is it worth knowing?

Comment: You need to create sets of virtual fonts and the infrastructure for defining the fonts in LaTeX, plus the encoding vectors for `pdftex.map`. Requires a lot of time and big expertise for something I wouldn't even think to: Times and Palatino cannot stand near to each other.

Comment: @egreg Em thanks for letting me know. Like cant we do something with "\DeclareMathAlphabet" command?? I have seen that mathsymbols can be altered from different packages, why not the text?

Comment: Can you tell us what you're trying to achieve by mixing-and-matching symbols from two entirely different math font families? Do you simply wish to create visually jarring clashes to distract your readers?